# Vintage terminal for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, terminal-emulator

So I have just been introduced to Cathode for OSX and I am completely fascinated by how classic it looks with it's 1970s retro style. Does anyone know of any programs/packages I can download to get my terminal to sport that very look? If there are no packages available, is there are setting I can change on the Ubuntu 14.04 terminal?

For those who are unaware of Cathode, I will post an image in reference to what I would like to have on my terminal:

[image: Cathode]

More information as to what Cathode does can be found on this link:

[Cathode Info](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2011/01/cathode-vintage-terminal-emulator/)

Comment: a world apart the 4k screen, retina display... :)

Comment: Can't help you with adding barrel distortion like Cathode does, but you can easily change gnome terminal's colors (edit->profile preferences->colors. green-on-black is one of the preconfigured themes.)

Comment: That's not too bad, I just think it's such a bummer that there is no software such as that for Ubuntu

Comment: A bunch of poseurs! What you need is one of these suckers: http://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Nvo.jpg ... and a sturdy desk. You need one of those too.

Comment: Lol @derobert im just looking for a program that does something similar to  cathode

Comment: I like this suggestion on the linked page: "There should be an option to take input from the camera and map it as a reflection on the screen".

Comment: @derobert You already know *that tish is bad for you* ;P  I was just looking at the screenshot here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146709/i-recently-cloned-my-drive-while-booting-i-have-to-wait-at-this-screen-which-ha and thinking, isn't this console mode in sunglasses?

Comment: @goldilocks I confess your joke has sailed over my head, but I posted an answer there anyway 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The software you are looking for is called ["cool-old-term" and is available on github](https://github.com/Swordifish90/cool-old-term).  It emulates the look of a CRT and is based around konsole (KDE's terminal) and requires QT 5.2 or newer.  The readme has instructions for getting it working on Ubuntu 14.04 and Arch.

[image: CRT image]

The examples on the github page show a few other variations on the CRT look and the presentation of the text.  This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AHNMh-vF-M) shows off the features of this terminal and the many ways it can look.

Comment: I like the look of that one better than Cathode.  It actually has a background rectangle in it as if the brightness were a bit high and fades slightly into the corner.

Comment: I have tried following the instructions. For one, I cannot punch in the `qmake && make && make install` command. When I do I get this: `qmake && make && make install`. Then when I try using `./cool-old-term` I get this: `file:///cool-old-term/app/main.qml:26 module "org.kde.konsole" is not installed` I have looked up how to resolve this online and the little support is available did not help when I followed their instructions. Any ideas?

Comment: @ryekayo Try installing konsole. Be advised this will probably pull in some kde dependencies.

Comment: @casey Thanks, got it to work. I had to update `QT` for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two applications built in as standard [*xscreensaver*](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html) modules that do some of this already - they're actual terminal emulators in their own right. One is `phosphor` and the other is `apple2`.  On my machine I can, for instance:

```
/usr/lib/xscreensaver/apple2 -text -fast -program /usr/bin/sh
```

And the *xscreensaver* module opens its own `pty` for `sh` and it works. I wouldn't call it *pretty*, but it works. Here are some [usage examples](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2006/02/glterminal/) for `apple2`.

I can do this with `phosphor`:

```
/usr/lib/xscreensaver/phosphor -scale 2 -delay 0 -program /usr/bin/sh
```

If you don't have the *xscreensaver* package installed it's bound to be available via package manager. Give it a try.

Both applications support multiple configuration settings - and both can draw on the root X window. It may be you can paint the background you desire with something like `feh` or `xv` and get pretty close to the same result.

Of course, [according to this](http://www.secretgeometry.com/apps/cathode/faq/) you can just buy that *Cathode* program for linux and that would do the trick, but I'm a little dubious as it seems the last update there was a couple years ago and the *try free* link seems to redirect to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [vinterm](https://code.google.com/p/vinterm/) from google project's page.
Doesn't look as feature complete as `Cathode` though.
Last code change was from a year ago.

Answer (score -1):

You can set Gnome Terminal to look this way.  When the terminal is running, click Edit > Profile Preferences.  Under the Colors tab, there is a `Built-in scheme` of `Green on black` that looks just like what you want.

**Update:** In reading the link you provide, it's clear that Cathode does much more than simply customize the colors of your terminal.  Much of Cathode's cool but advanced feature set (simulating an old curved cathode ray screen, for example, or adding flicker and other video artifacts common with such technology) is not available in Gnome Terminal, but you can at least get the *look* of phosphorous green on black.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure of any software that does it. But I did the following to make my terminal look as cathode. You can look for `tput` command and may be change the font size and look to make the settings permanent in the user configuration file.

```
tput bold
tput setab black
tput setaf 2
```

To make the settings permanent, I added the above mentioned lines to `/home/.bashrc`. After that, I closed the terminal and opened the terminal. Now, my terminal looks like below.

[image]

Comment: I tried that out, the effects are not permanent though

Comment: @ryekayo, see the updates.

Comment: Tried that as well, not a permanent effect either.

Comment: @ryekayo you can make it permanent by changing the settings with the menus. But this will not give you the 3d effect.