# I recently cloned my drive, while booting I have to wait at this screen which has a number of error messages

Tags: debian, boot, ssd, clonezilla

Once booted the computer works fine (debian 7 sid), no other issues.

I just have to wait at this screen for around 3 minutes, unfortunate since I have an SSD.

Are these error messages causing the wait time?

Is it one specific error message causing it?

How do I go about resolving the error?

This seems to be causing the hold up:

```
Jul 26 14:58:00 Optimus systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1f4e32fd\x2ddf53\x2d4c2a\x2d9939\x2d7d5d93250655.device.
Jul 26 14:58:00 Optimus systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/1f4e32fd-df53-4c2a-9939-7d5d93250655.
Jul 26 14:58:00 Optimus systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swap.
```

What do I do about this device that no longer exists?

[image: screenshot of boot]

Comment: Check your `/etc/fstab` for the mentioned UUID (probably your swap partition) and update it to the correct value. You can get the UUID by running `ls -la /dev/disk/by-id`. After updating `fstab` you may have to update your grub as well (probably `update-grub`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try booting in recovery mode (select via grub). This way you may see more output. There is also a kernel command line option that you can set (I believe you have to make sure `quiet` is not set).

Also you may want to check the journal after boot has finished. It may be the case that systemd is waiting for some devices that are not present (probably because the UUID is different now).

When you show us more details we can help you further investigate.

Comment: Ah I see, okay, I'll try and gather some more info. Thanks.

Comment: By the way: You can use `journalctl` to view the journal [more information](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Journal)

Comment: I think you're right, journalctl helped a lot, there seems to be a UUID that isn't present now. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, swap is configured in `/etc/fstab`. It sounds like you have a swap device configured there which doesn't exist.

If you intend to have swap, you need to change the UUID to the one that actually exists on your system.